# Oracle PL/SQL where condition: not equal to 0 or null

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am selecting `id` where it cannot be equal to 0, nor can the value be `(null)`. I wrote:

```
WHERE id IS NOT NULL (+) and id not in ('0')
```

I got 2 errors

> Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(38,119): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   I change it to:

```
WHERE id IS NOT NULL (+) and id is not ('0')
```

Same errors occurred. What should I write as the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify the condition to just:

```
WHERE id != 0
```

because comparisions with NULL (using both = or != operators) always evaluates to NULL (which is treated in SQL as "false" in conditions), 
therefore NULL != 0 always evaluates to FALSE and you can skip this part in this condition

```
WHRE id != 0 AND id IS NOT NULL
```

---

Braiam's answer `Where nvl(Id,0)<>0`, although correct, will prevent database from using an index on `id` column, and this could have bad impact on the performce.

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be

```
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
AND id != 0
```

Answer (score 5):

(+) is for outer joins. You should write:

```
Where nvl(Id,0)<>0
```

Comment: if I have another condition, should I just put `Where [condition] AND nvl(id,0)<>0`?

Comment: Don't use [] to enclose predicates in PLSQL it wont compile. Use regular brackets if you need. You can have as many logical expressions as you need.